# Predicting numerical features based on string features using sk-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, encoder

I am trying to predict the '`Full_Time_Home_Goals`' column (feature).
I have followed the [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/jeffd23/scikit-learn-ml-from-start-to-finish) example. The code works with the varied dimensions as in my example (419 rows in test data and 892 rows in train data)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# %matplotlib inline

# Set option to display all the rows and columns in the dataset. If there are more rows, adjust number accordingly.
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

# Files
data_train = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\harsh\Documents\My Dream\Desktop\Machine Learning\Attempt 3\train.csv")
data_test = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\harsh\Documents\My Dream\Desktop\Machine Learning\Attempt 3\test.csv")


columns = ['Id', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'Full_Time_Home_Goals']
col = ['Id', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']
data_test = data_test[col]
data_train = data_train[columns]

data_train = data_train.dropna()
data_test = data_test.dropna()

data_train['Full_Time_Home_Goals'] = data_train['Full_Time_Home_Goals'].astype(int)

from sklearn import preprocessing


def encode_features(df_train, df_test):
    features = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']
    df_combined = pd.concat([df_train[features], df_test[features]])

    for feature in features:
        le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        le = le.fit(df_combined[feature])
        df_train[feature] = le.transform(df_train[feature])
        df_test[feature] = le.transform(df_test[feature])
    return df_train, df_test


data_train, data_test = encode_features(data_train, data_test)
print(data_train.head())
print(data_test.head())

# X_all would contain all columns required for prediction and y_all would have that one columns we want to predict

X_all = data_train

y_all = data_train['Full_Time_Home_Goals']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

num_test = 0.20  # 80-20 split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_all, y_all, test_size=num_test, random_state=23)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Using Random Forest and using parameters that we defined

clf = RandomForestClassifier()

parameters = {'n_estimators': [4, 6, 9],
              'max_features': ['log2', 'sqrt', 'auto'],
              'criterion': ['entropy', 'gini'],
              'max_depth': [2, 3, 5, 10],
              'min_samples_split': [2, 3, 5],
              'min_samples_leaf': [1, 5, 8]
              }

acc_scorer = make_scorer(accuracy_score)

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, scoring=acc_scorer)
grid_obj = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf = grid_obj.best_estimator_

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
```

The errors I am getting is :

1. With the code as is:

   > Traceback (most recent call last):
   > File "C:/Users/harsh/PycharmProjects/Kaggle-Machine Learning from Start to Finish with Scikit-Learn/EPL Predicting.py", line 98, in
   >
   > predictions = clf.predict(data_test.drop('Id', axis=1))
   > File "C:\Users\harsh\PycharmProjects\GitHub\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble_forest.py",
   > line 629, in predict
   > ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 4 and input n_features is 2
2. With the code changed from `predictions = clf.predict(data_test.drop('Id', axis=1))` `to predictions = clf.predict(X_test)`, the error is:

   ```
    raise ValueError(msg) ValueError: array length 37921 does not match index length 380
   ```

How do I resolve this issue?

[My datasets used can be found here](https://gofile.io/d/JNSNFn)

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter; the same holds true for commented-out code (edited out).

Comment: With `X_all = data_train` you have probably left your *label* column `'Full_Time_Home_Goals'` in the features.

Comment: Try to change `X_all = data_train; y_all = data_train['Full_Time_Home_Goals']` to `y_all = data_train['Full_Time_Home_Goals']; X_all = data_train.drop(['Full_Time_Home_Goals'],axis=1)` and see if this helps. Also consider the above advice on cutting your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is tested and fully working code of yours:

```
data_train = pd.read_csv(r"train.csv")
data_test = pd.read_csv(r"test.csv")


columns = ['Id', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam', 'Full_Time_Home_Goals']
col = ['Id', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']
data_test = data_test[col]
data_train = data_train[columns]

data_train = data_train.dropna()
data_test = data_test.dropna()

data_train['Full_Time_Home_Goals'] = data_train['Full_Time_Home_Goals'].astype(int)

from sklearn import preprocessing


def encode_features(df_train, df_test):
    features = ['HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']
    df_combined = pd.concat([df_train[features], df_test[features]])

    for feature in features:
        le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        le = le.fit(df_combined[feature])
        df_train[feature] = le.transform(df_train[feature])
        df_test[feature] = le.transform(df_test[feature])
    return df_train, df_test


data_train, data_test = encode_features(data_train, data_test)
print(data_train.head())
print(data_test.head())

# X_all would contain all columns required for prediction and y_all would have that one columns we want to predict

y_all = data_train['Full_Time_Home_Goals']
X_all = data_train.drop(['Full_Time_Home_Goals'], axis=1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

num_test = 0.20  # 80-20 split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_all, y_all, test_size=num_test, random_state=23)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# Using Random Forest and using parameters that we defined

clf = RandomForestClassifier()

parameters = {'n_estimators': [4, 6, 9],
              'max_features': ['log2', 'sqrt', 'auto'],
              'criterion': ['entropy', 'gini'],
              'max_depth': [2, 3, 5, 10],
              'min_samples_split': [2, 3, 5],
              'min_samples_leaf': [1, 5, 8]
              }

acc_scorer = make_scorer(accuracy_score)

grid_obj = GridSearchCV(clf, parameters, scoring=acc_scorer)
grid_obj = grid_obj.fit(X_train, y_train)

clf = grid_obj.best_estimator_

clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = clf.predict(X_test)

print(accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))

ids = data_test['Id']
predictions = clf.predict(data_test)

df_preds = pd.DataFrame({"id":ids, "predictions":predictions})
df_preds

   Id  HomeTeam  AwayTeam  Full_Time_Home_Goals
0   1        55       440                     3
1   2       158       493                     2
2   3       178       745                     1
3   4       185       410                     1
4   5       249        57                     2
       Id  HomeTeam  AwayTeam
0  190748       284        54
1  190749       124       441
2  190750       446        57
3  190751       185       637
4  190752       749       482
0.33213786556261704
id  predictions
0   190748  1
1   190749  1
2   190750  1
3   190751  1
4   190752  1
... ... ...
375 191123  1
376 191124  1
377 191125  1
378 191126  1
379 191127  1
380 rows × 2 columns
```

Comment: This works! I finally have an output! Phew! Million thanks Sergey. I have run around circles for so long till here! The further is obviously out of scope of the question however, I noticed all predicted values as 1. You should not have all the same values right? What do you think I am missing here?

Comment: The accuracy of your model is .33 and all predictions, as you noticed, are 1, which is a sign of some problem. You may wish to check this accuracy against baseline or pure guessing majority class. Regardless, a simple answer to your question might be (1) find better model (2) make more features the model may learn. I would start with the second. The suggestions are based on the assumption the outcome is learnable indeed.

Comment: When I introduced features containing float, I got `TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['float', 'str']`  and `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'` How can I overcome this? Example data:          HomeTeam     AwayTeam  FTHG  B365H  B365D  B365A  B365>2.5  B365<2.5
0         Arsenal     Man City     3    1.5    1.5    1.5       1.5       1.5
1         Chelsea      Norwich     2    1.5    1.5    1.5       1.5       1.5
2        Coventry    Wimbledon     1    1.5    1.5    1.5       1.5       1.5

Comment: I think a good place to start is documents (or error message at least). Your `encode_features` function, specifically `LabelEncoder`, requires features to be either strings or integers. If you plan on feeding floats through your model, you need to (1) separate floats and strings (2) encode strings with your func, (3) concat floats back (4) feed data to model. You need to ensure consistency between what you're doing to your train and test datasets.

Comment: Is there any library (unsupervised) that can do this kind of predicting? Tensorflow or otherwise? Can you point me in the direction?

Comment: If you mean predicting per se, any (supervised) algo will do. If by "predicting" you mean data preprocessing, you need specify yourself what you want to do with your data.